# How to get started with SOAP?

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to get started with SOAP, I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Using-SOAP-with-PHP/3/

As far as I can tell I've got everything I need installed.

```
soap
Soap Client    enabled
Soap Server    enabled

Directive   Local Value   Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache   1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir   /tmp   /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled   1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl   86400   86400
```

When I try to run the following code I get the errors below

```
<?php

function getStockQuote($symbol) {

    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db('captainc_general');
    $query = "SELECT stock_price FROM stockprices "
       . "WHERE stock_symbol = '$symbol'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['stock_price'];
}


require_once('nusoap.php'); //use the nusoap library 

$server = new soap_server();

$server->configureWSDL('stockserver', 'urn:stockquote');

$server->register("getStockQuote",
                array('symbol' => 'xsd:string'),
                array('return' => 'xsd:decimal'),
                'urn:stockquote',
                'urn:stockquote#getStockQuote');

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)
                  ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

> Warning: require_once(nusoap.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/captainc/public_html/soap/soaptest.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'nusoap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/captainc/public_html/soap/soaptest.php on line 17

Anyone got any ideas what I need to do to sort this?

Comment: I'd just run away and never look back if I was you....

Comment: Where did you put `nusoap.php`?

Comment: I'm assuming you have no flexibility to use REST instead, right? PHP support for SOAP is quite poor, I'd try to stay away as far as possible.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory to me...

Comment: Got it sorted,nusoap.php installation problem :)

Comment: @user1532669: Please add your solution as an answer below (and mark it as accepted) for the benefit of future visitors.